# spark driver not found

Tags: apache-spark, jtds

I am trying to write dataframe to sqlserver using spark. I am using the method write for dataframewriter to write to sql server.
Using DriverManager.getConnection I am able to get connection of sqlserver and able to write but when using jdbc method and passing uri I am getting "No suitable driver found".
I have passed the jtds jar in the --jars in spark-shell. 
Spark version : 1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that spark is not finding driver jar file. So download jar and place in all worker nodes of spark cluster on the same path and add this path to SPARK_CLASSPATH in spark-env.sh file
as follow

```
SPARK_CLASSPATH=/home/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar
```

hope it will help

Comment: I am passing the jars in the --jar as comma seperated list.

Comment: can you see your jar on spark ui in environment tab? if not then spark is not picking your jar. you can try by adding in spark classpath

Comment: yes I can see them. I can see this is a bug in apache spark 1.4 version. I will have to pass the classapth explicitly for both driver and executor in the command line arguments

Comment: Thanks Hafiz..I have set the class path to get this working but not able to append to a table when giving this command  df1.mode("append").write.jdbc("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://noi-nipuna-w81/sams","sams", props) where  df1 is a dataframe, I get object name sams already exists

Comment: I have not worked with spark 1.4. but i achieved same thing with spark 1.3.1 and mysql recently. using dataFrame.insertintoJDBCTable method.

Comment: http://www.sparkexpert.com/2015/04/17/save-apache-spark-dataframe-to-database/   
 this like will be helpful for u

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83138/discussion-between-hafiz-mujadid-and-nipun).

Comment: A lot of methods have been deprecated of dataframe in spark 1.4. I am not able to find out as to why it is not taking the mode property